# Same notation/terminology for union of sets and concatenation (Kleene star)?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, discrete-mathematics, notation

> For the union of sets we use the union operator $\cup$ (or $\bigcup$). And for a concatenation (Kleene star) we also use the union operator. The operations are different, but why the same terminology and operator?

The following is my understanding of the union of sets versus the concatenation of sets (Kleene star). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

**Union of sets**

For the two sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ we have the union 
\begin{align}
\{a,b\}\cup\{a,b\}=\{a,b\} \tag 1
\end{align}
***Update:*** For reference I used [Union (set theory) from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Union_of_two_sets).

**Concatenation of sets (Kleene star)**

The concatenation of $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ is also a union *(same notation?!)* of two sets
\begin{align}
\{a,b\}^*&=\bigcup _{i=0}^{2} \{a,b\} ^2 \tag 2\\
&=\{a,b\} \cup \{a,b\} \tag 3\\
&=\{\epsilon,a,b,aa,ab,ba,bb,aaa,aab,aba,abb,baa,\dots\} \tag 4
\end{align}

***Update:*** For reference  I used [Kleene star from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star#Definition_and_notation). And here's where my confusion lies because at Wikipedia they also use the notation with the union operator:
$$
V^* = \bigcup_{i\geq 0} V^i = V^0\cup V^1 \cup V^2 \cup V^3 \cup V^4 \cup \cdots \tag 4
$$
Which is the same (?!) notation as in my $(2) - (3)$ but with the upper bound $2$. And the notation does not coincide with $(1)$.

Comment: I have never seen $\cup$ used for concatenation. That would be very awkward, given the usual meaning of $\cup$. Do you have a reference?

Comment: The Kleene star is the union of an infinite number of sets (if you look at it that way, which is possibly not the best way to think of it). Concatenation, on the other hand, is not a union; it's a concatenation. And I don't understand either of the equalities in the equation you show, since they are both evidently wrong.

Comment: Hi @YuvalFilmus ! That is exactly why I'm confused.  I updated with references. Feel free to clarify my misunderstanding.

Comment: Hi @rici ! I updated with references and numbered the equations. Feel free to correct what is wrong.

Comment: Wikipedia uses $\cup$ in its usual meaning, set union.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia is using $\cup$ in its usual meaning, set union. When Wikipedia defines
$$
V^* = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} V^n = V^0 \cup V^1  \cup V^2 \cup \cdots,
$$
it literally means that $V^*$ is the union of the sets $V^0,V^1,V^2,\ldots$

The concatenation happens in the definition of $V^n$, which can be defined as follows: $V^0 = \{\epsilon\}$, and $V^{n+1} = \{ xy : x \in V^n, y \in V \}$. In words, $V^n$ is the concatenation of $n$ words from $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation of two sets of strings is the set of all pairwise concatenations of their elements: $AB = \{ xy \mid x \in A, y \in B \}$. For instance, the concatenation of $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ is $\{aa, ab, ba, bb\}$.

Now we can write

- $A^2 = AA$ = all strings that are 2 strings from $A$ concatenated
- $A^3 = AAA$ = all strings that are 3 strings from $A$ concatenated
- $A^4 = AAAA$ = all strings that are 4 strings from $A$ concatenated
- and so forth, and, for consistency,
- $A^1 = A$ = all strings that are 1 string from $A$ concatenated
- $A^0 = \{ \epsilon \}$ = all strings that are 0 strings from $A$ concatenated

Now the Kleene star of a set $A$ is the set $A^*$ formed by all strings consisting of *arbitrarily many* concatenations of strings from $A$. That is to say: such a string is

- *either* 0 strings from $A$ concatenated (it is in $A^0$)
- *or* 1 string from $A$ concatenated  (it is in $A^1$)
- *or* 2 strings from $A$ concatenated (it is in $A^2$)
- *or*, ...

In other words: $\displaystyle A^* = \bigcup_{n}{A^n}$. The *either ... or* is where the union comes from.

You also wrote: correct me if I'm wrong. Well, you wrote this:

> \begin{align} \{a,b\}^*&=\bigcup _{i=0}^{2} \{a,b\} ^2 \tag 2\\
>   &=\{a,b\} \cup \{a,b\} \tag 3\\
>   &=\{\epsilon,a,b,aa,ab,ba,bb,aaa,aab,aba,abb,baa,\dots\} \tag 4
>   \end{align}

Line (2) is just a weird way of writing $\{ a, b \} \cup \{ a, b \} \cup \{ a, b \}$.
This is indeed equal to $\{ a, b \} \cup \{ a, b \}$ (3), which in turn is equal to $\{ a, b \}$. No string concatenation is going on at all here, so you're not getting any other elements than just $a$ and $b$. In (4), suddenly, you have a lot of concatenations. Clearly, that can't be right. You must have miscopied this from a source in which (2) and (3) were different.